# Kafka Stream Internal Topics lag increases on taking Kafka Broker down

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams Application version - 0.11.0.1 which takes data from few topics and joins the data and puts it in another topic.

Kafka Configuration:

```
5 kafka brokers - version 0.11
Kafka Topics - 15 partitions and 3 replication factor.
```

Few millions of records are consumed/produced every hour.

**Note: Whenever I take any kafka broker down, it brings down few consumers and Kafka streams (consumer) rebalances and lag of internal topics increase from 0 - few millions(1-10).**

Is this because of any local state store config or something? How can I handle this?

Comment: Did you try to configure StandbyTasks ?

Comment: Yes I have num.standby tasks configured to 1

Comment: Since my few Kafka stream instance went down on taking broker offline/down, instance which had the standby might have also been brought down.. I think because of this it happened. But I feel it should not start consuming internal topics from beginning

Comment: Maybe it's related to this: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#why-is-my-application-re-processing-data-from-the-beginning